# Excel: Count if values match

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I basically have two predetermined worksheets with data in a format I can't modify the way it populates.

On one sheet "SSP" I want to check row I against row E on a different sheet "YMS" to check for the same string of numbers and letters

I just need to check for duplicates between the two sheets and total them so I can subtract them from another formula so the values aren't double-counted.

Another issue is that the values aren't exact. For instance the one cell on "SSP" will say "AZNG V210354 !" whereas the other sheet will have a cell that just says "v210354" so I'll probably need wildcards incorporated. Also, I don't want it to count any blanks as matches.

Hopefully that's not confusing.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

***TO SUMMARIZE, I want the formula to check column A of sheet "YMS" for a specific value "MSP1", when found, check row E in that same row against row I on sheet "SSP" to find a match and count it, allowing wildcards preceding and following.

Comment: You should try to explain this much more clearly.  See [how to ask](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question.

Answer (score 0):

basic INDEX & MATCH logic will work for you. The logic is that the MATCH pinpoints the coordinate(row number) and the INDEX gets the value.
Do not forget to update *ranges* and *specific value* in formula:

```
=INDEX(SSP!E2:E1000,MATCH(<specific value>,YMS!E2:E1000,0),1)
```

Comment: Admittedly this question is not very clear, but **read the last paragraph**.  There are *two* lookups required.  Also, you have completely ignored OP's request for using wildcards.  If you would like  to contribute here, please read the questions *carefully*.  Thanks.